# Update path does not exist. / Error updating COM_INSTALLER_TYPE_TYPE_

Tags: extensions, update, extension-update, joomla-3.9

Since upgrading to J! 3.9.0 I'm getting this error on EVERY extension update except for the few who use an update routine that appears to bypass normal Joomla workings - StackIdea's EasyBlog and JoomlaShine's Uniform are 2 that will still update OK.

However, everything else (ALL of which have happily updated from the Update area in the past) fails. The extensions are all 3 types (component, module, and plugin) and are both paid and free. They all require manual installation to update.

I checked my /tmp path and it's correct and writable. configuration.php is, as I would expect, unwritable, but I saw in a different post some else's Folder Permissions screenshot showing it as writable so I changed it to 777. Still fail to install anything.

As I manage some 80 odd sites, this is a major time waster. Is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the issue and solution, but not the cause!

I went to the thread On RegularLabs' site - [https://www.regularlabs.com/forum/exten ... ions#83452](https://www.regularlabs.com/forum/exten%20...%20ions#83452). In this, Peter talks about "some" server setting (he doesn't know which - or didn't at the time of writing) changing the case of the Header names. Because Joomla is looking case-sensitive, the installs failed.

He posted a patch for libraries/src/Installer/InstallerHelper/php which I copied and saved, then uploaded to 2 of my sites. Previously failing updates now performed perfectly.

Comment: I've just installed v3.9.1, which should include this patch, but I still get this error. Any advice?

Comment: @Puce if you are experiencing a similar issue, but this solution doesn't work for you, please post a new question with as much detail as you can so that volunteers can possibly lend you a hand.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the system has free space.
2. Check in `System / Global Configuration / Server Tab / Path to Temp
   Folder` if you have a full path (not relative one) to the tmp folder
   of your website.
3. Check in `System / Global Configuration / System Tab / Path to
   LogFolder` if you have a full path (not relative one) to the logs
   folder of your website.
4. Check in `System / System Information / Folder Permissions tab` if
   all the item are writable

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  I see that you are no stranger to StackExchange, but please take our  [tour] to see what slightly differs here.  Thank you for joining us and contributing.

Comment: Can you tell me what I did wrong with my answer?. I had a similar problem like the question said and I posted my solution. nothing more.

Comment: You did nothing wrong that I see. I welcomed you and upvoted your post.